# Xcode Capitalizes #import

Tags: xcode

About 500 times every day, Xcode corrects `#import` to `#Import` (the latter being wrong). This is maddening, and I don't want to shut off capitalization autocorrection system-wide. Is there a setting in Xcode?

Comment: Is IntelliSense turned on your system ?

Comment: `I type #Import though I've actually typed #import`, statement is confusing. You intend to type `#import` but mistakenly type `#Import`. Is that correct ?

Comment: @Mahesh, corrected question to make it clearer, thanks. I do have code completion on, yes.

Comment: @Yar - That might be the reason for viewers viewing now my suggestion seems irrelevant and cause downvoting ;)

Comment: @Yar - Does that happen when you try to compile the code ?

Comment: @Yar, "....and I don't want to shut off capitalization autocorrection system-wide" What capitalization autocorrection are you referring to?

Comment: @NSGod, this one, I think: http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20010792-263.html It shows up in all applications including browsers, textmate, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that there's some existing code in the project -- somewhere that's included everywhere like `main.m` or `YourProjectName_Prefix.pch`, or in some class you're including nearly everywhere -- that has **`#Import`** in it with the capital `I`. As a result **Code Sense** is offering it as its first option.

Try a *Textual* Project Find for `#Import` with *Ignore case* unchecked and see if you can find it.

If not then it's possible that the Code Sense cache is referencing something that no longer exists. From the *Build* menu choose *Clean All Targets*, which should recreate the cache.
**EDITED TO ADD** Rebuilding the index actually requires going to *Project Settings*, choosing the *General* tab, and clicking the *Rebuild Code Sense Index* button.

Comment: Thanks. While that's promising, 1) a find didn't bring anything up and 2) it's consistent across projects.

Comment: Wow, cross-project. That's really strange. I had just remembered the "Rebuild Code Sense Index" button in the General tab of Project Settings, but I guess that's not going to work for you.

Comment: This is not actually best answer, but I have to pick one for my approval rating. The problem has been resolved with time.

Answer (score 1):

Ahah. You are using Xcode 4.0, aren't you? (Just a note that since it hasn't been released publicly, we are actually breaking our NDA by talking about it).

Since Xcode 4.0 is still very much in-the-works, they haven't disabled that feature of the spell checker. The option to autocorrect spelling isn't even present in Xcode 3.x.

I'd consider this a bug in Xcode 4 that needs to be addressed; you could file a radar if you like: http://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: 3.2.5. I do enough for Apple already. I really don't need to beta test their software too, do I?